# Returning the highest values from multiple selections

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I got a datasheet that looks like this:

[image]

And based on this data I want to make a sheet that looks like this:

[image]

So what did I do to get to the second picture?

- In the data from the first picture I searched for all the Numberswith6+digits that have the same first 6 numbers. That gives us 2 results, 445566 that exists 3 times and 112233 that exists 2 times.
- From there I want to find the highest percentage for each result, so what is the highest percantage in %store for 445566, that's 10%.
- After doing this for every store you get one line for each 6 number result with all the highest % per store.

As you can imagine, doing this by hand is quite time consuming. I was wondering if anyone knows how I could speed this up. I thought of trying to use Vlookup/VBA, but I don't quite understand enough of these subjects to solve this problem (basic knowledge of Vlookup and almost non-existant knowledge of VBA). I was wondering if any of you can send me in the right direction or have any ideas that can make this process easier.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: link of data picture 1: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By2vDlsDCzUoZ1BocV9qVjQ4bzg

Comment: I'm sorry but I really do not feel like retyping all of your data so just do a search for maxif or maxifs.

Comment: Agree with above. But a simple way to group by the six digits is to use =LEFT(A2,6) and with that create a helper column.

Comment: Yeah sorry, but I somehow couldn't get a table working (even when following the exact description in advanced help...). Here is a link with the data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By2vDlsDCzUoZ1BocV9qVjQ4bzg

I understand that maxif should be usefull in my case, but it isn't enough to get the result of picture 2 if I understand correctly?

Comment: Create a column with the first 6 digits then use a pivot table.

Comment: Scott Craner your answer was the easiest way to do this! Thanks a lot! (the other answers are good as well, but this was way easier for me, since you let Excel do all the work)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($A8,$A$2:$A$6)),B$2:B$6,0%))
```

Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>
and drag it down and in the same row
First Create the Column of 6 digits starting in A8 for example
A2:A8 the column of Numbers
B2:B6 % store
change it to correspond the Data in the first Table
Keep the $ for fixed references so it change the right way

Comment: I am currently away from my computer, but I will try this tomorrow morning. Will let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 2):

Put the following formula in cel H2. Use 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copy down.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LEFT($A$2:$A$100,6), MATCH(0,COUNTIF($H$1:H1, LEFT($A$2:$A$100,6)), 0)),"")
```

This will give you the unique 6 digit numbers.

Then put the next formula in cell I2 use 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> again. Copy down and to the right.

```
=MAX(IF(LEFT($A$2:$A$100,6)=$H2,B$2:B$100))
```

The second formula will provide the max percentages per unique number, per store.

Answer (score 1):

In H2:J2 per the supplied image,

```
'as an array formula with CSE in H2
=--LEFT(INDEX(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, A:A)), MATCH(0, COUNTIF(H$1:H1, LEFT(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, A:A)), 6)&""), 0)), 6)
'as a standard formula in I2
=MAX(INDEX((B$2:INDEX(F:F, MATCH(1E+99, F:F)))-(--LEFT(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, F:F)), 6)<>H2)*1E+99, , ))
'as a standard formula in J2
=INDEX(A$1:F$1, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(A:F)/((--LEFT(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, F:F)), 6)=H2)*COUNTIF(I2, A$2:INDEX(F:F, MATCH(1E+99, F:F)))), 1))
```

Fill down as necessary. Add IFERROR wrappers to avoid error codes when you run out of things to match.

[image]

Comment: You didn't actually ask for the associated store but I figured you were going to sooner or later.